# Difference while running KTR manually and through java

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04, kettle, postgresql-8.4

Hie All,

I use KTR (kettle files) to update my database from POS to ERP, I want to know what is the difference while running KTR manually through terminal and running through java file. I use Ubuntu 12.04 OS for both ERP and POS Systems, Postgres 8.4 as DB.

example of running KTR manually:

```
manideep@manideep:~$ /home/manideep/data-integration/pan.sh -file='/home/manideep/resources/ORDERS.ktr' --level=Minimal
```

example of running KTR through java

```
private void callAttributeSync(String gmno) throws KettleException {

    KettleEnvironment.init();
    TransMeta metaData = new TransMeta(
            "/home/manideep/resources/ORDERS.ktr");
    Trans trans = new Trans(metaData);
    trans.setLogLevel(LogLevel.ROWLEVEL);
    trans.execute(null);
    trans.waitUntilFinished();
    if (trans.getErrors() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Error while ORDER Transformation");
    }else{
                    System.out.println("Succesfully Completed ORDER Transformation");

            }
}
```

I Strongly believe that there is some difference in both the executions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What difference in behaviour are you actually seeing? Probably just your environment is different?  same user? same kettle.properties? same JVM version?

Comment: Yes.. All same.. But I feel some errors on server side are ignored manually and shown when done via java @codek

Comment: Are you using Maven to create your project, can you share what dependencies you had to pull into your Java project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When executing through JAVA , Exceptions can be handled and server response also can be read. When running manually Exceptions/responses cannot be handled.